# Emulate ARM Android GSI image on Windows

Tags: android, windows, virtual-machine, emulation, qemu

I am trying to run an ARM64 Android on my PC to test an app which is not compatible with x86_64 architecture.
I downloaded android build from https://developer.android.com/topic/generic-system-image/releases and tried using QEMU with it.
The only thing I see after all - a machine monitor console but not Android GUI. I didn't see any errors at all.

Can anyone tell me how to properly run such images that require exactly ARM architecture and access usual GUI?

my command to run qemu:

`qemu-system-aarch64 -cdrom system.img -m 4000 -hda vlomatel.img -machine virt -boot menu=on`

system.img is from Android releases, vlomatel.img is a volume created using qemu-img with size 16GB

Comment: Just making sure you've seen: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/run-arm-apps-on-android-emulator.html